# 'invisible' physics object glitch Corona SDK

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk, physics

Ok, I'm making a physics game with Corona SDK. To fire a ball, you pull back and release, the linear impulse is based on that distance. The ball is a sprite with 2 frames, so you can change the color of the ball. When I change the frame of the ball, which is in a different "settings" scene, and go back to the "level1" scene, the ball hits and bounces off 'invisible' objects. Also, the linear impulse applied is much greater than it should be. If I change the frame back it doesn't fix anything. Any thoughts on what this could be? Thanks!

Comment: Probably the physics elements are not being removed when you change scene and when you come back you create another ones. You can see what is going on if you add this line of code physics.setDrawMode("hybrid")

Comment: @BrunoDomingues Thanks! You were right. How do I remove the elements? I've looked everywhere and I can't find how.

Comment: If you have inserted the elements in the scene when you exit it should remove automatically. Have you inserted them? If yes, it means that you scene is not being removed from memory when you change scene. But to remove the physics elements you just have to call element:removeSelf() and the body will be removed too.

Comment: @BrunoDomingues How do you insert the elements in the scene? Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: @BrunoDomingues  Thanks for your help, I fixed it. I did have the objects in the scene, I just forgot to stop physics!